# How to programmatically change image of RibbonMenuButton

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I'm coding right now application basen on Ribbon. I know how to put image on my RibbonMenuButton from .xaml file, but I can't change it after clicking. How can I achieve that?

```
<Custom:RibbonMenuButton Name="menuConnect" LargeImageSource="Resources/Main/connect.png" Label="Connect">
    <Custom:RibbonMenuItem Name="menuWConnect" Click="MenuConnect_Click" ImageSource="Resources/Main/ConnectOn.png"/>
 </Custom:RibbonMenuButton>
```

And in .cs code I have:

```
menuConnect.LargeImageSource = "someImage.png";
```

It doesn't work for me. How can I change it?

Comment: Try something like this `menuConnect.LargeImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/someImage.png", UriKind.Relative));`

Comment: It works fine! What about memory? Do I have extra copy on every attempt?

Comment: Don't worry about memory, .net takes care :)

Comment: Provided that `someImage.png` is a resource file (with `Build Action` set to `Resource`) in a folder called `Images` in your Visual Studio project, you should load it by a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly), like `new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/someImage.png"))`.